# Are Li's numbers $\lambda_n$ absolutely convergent for $n>1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions

Li's numbers  $\{\lambda_n\}$ are defined as $$\lambda_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^n}{ds^n} [s^{n-1}\log\xi(s)]_{s=1} $$ for all positive integers $n$.
Also $\lambda_n$ is given as a sum over the non trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ by
$$\lambda_n=\sum_{\rho}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{1}{\rho}\right)^n\right] $$ where $\rho$ are the non trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

> My question is: **Are the $\lambda_n$'s absolutely convergent for $n>1$**?

An article of Mark W. Coffey "On certian sums over the non trivial zeta zeros" the year being (2010) says in line 1 p.2 that fot $n>1$, $\lambda_n$ is absolutely convergent, while for $\lambda_1$ the sum should be taken over complex conjugate pairs of zeros of increasing imaginary part.

An answer or a reference is desired.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Riemann hypothesis $\rho=\frac12+i\gamma$, then
$$1-\frac{1}{\rho}=-\frac{\frac12-i\gamma}{\frac12+i\gamma}=e^{2i\theta},\qquad 
\theta=\arctan\frac{1}{2\gamma}.$$
$$\sum_\rho\Bigl[1-\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{\rho}\Bigr)^n\Bigr]=\sum_\gamma\bigl(1-e^{2in\theta}\bigr).$$
Here $n$ is fixed and for $\gamma\to+\infty$
$$1-e^{2in\theta}\sim 2n\theta\sim \frac{n}{\gamma}$$
Since $\gamma_k\sim 2\pi k/\log k$ the series is equivalent to
$$n\sum_k\frac{\log k}{2\pi k}$$
therefore is divergent.

When $\rho$ is associated with $\overline{\rho}$
we obtain
$$2\sum_{\gamma>0} \Re(1-e^{2in\theta})=4\sum_{\gamma>0}\sin^2(n\theta)\sim 
4n^2\sum_k\frac{(\log k)^2}{4\pi^2k^2},$$
that is absolutely convergent.

There are several papers dealing with the asymptotic value of $\lambda_n$.

Comment: Thank you. So you assumed the Riemann Hypothesis. What if we do not assume the Riemann Hypothesis. Will combining $\rho$ with $\bar{\rho}$ will we have absolute convergence?

Comment: In this post on Math. SE, the answer is given irrespective of the truth of the Riemann Hypothesis. Please see here- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921175/are-lis-numbers-conditionally-or-absolutely-convergent

Comment: @Rama1729 yes the RH is not required, but the argument is slightly more complex. But apparently you knew the answer.

Comment: Thank you. It would be of great help if you would edit your answer and prove it without assuming RH. Thanks again.

Comment: How can we associate $\rho$ with $\bar{\rho}$. Will this association not require the absolute convergence of the sum?

Comment: Please edit the answer. I will be obliged to give it a check mark. It is a request.

Comment: One doesn;t need to use RH just the standard (and actually not that hard fact to prove by general theory of entire functions) that $\sum 1/\rho^k$ is absolutely convergent for $k \ge 2$ and that $\sum 1/\rho$ is conditionally but not absolutely convergent;  $\lambda_n= n\sum 1/\rho +S_n$ where $S_n$ is absolutely convergent as a sum of $1/\rho^k, 2 \le k \le n$ with coefficients depending on $n$, so $\lambda_n$ cannot be absolutely convergent as is, but it is convergent conditionally precisely like $\sum 1/\rho$; so most likely the OP claim about that statement in a paper is just a typo

Comment: Note that the original paper of Li referred to by Coffey does not claim absolute convergence of the sum and instead pairs $\rho$ with $1-\rho$ (which is roughly equivalent to pairing $\rho$ with $\overline{\rho}$, and exactly equivalent on RH); see Lemma 3.1 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X97921375?via%3Dihub

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. Can we find an upper bound for $\lambda_n$ which is independent of $n$?

Comment: @Terry Tao Thank you. Can we find an upper bound for $\lambda_n$ which is independent of $n$?

Comment: This seems unlikely.  Just the contribution of those zeroes with $|\rho| \sim n$ are likely to give quite a large contribution (maybe of the order of $n \log n$, if my back of the envelope calculations are accurate).

Comment: @Terry Tao Thank you for your comment. But then how will $\lambda_n$'s be absolutely convergent? It is dependent on $n$. Sorry if I am missing something trivial.

Comment: For each $n$, the sum $\sum_\rho 1 - (1-1/\rho)^n$ defining $\lambda_n$ is convergent.  However I do not think anyone is claiming the series $\sum_n \lambda_n$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @Terry Tao Thank you so much. But if we combine the zero $\rho$ with $\bar{\rho}$ then is the series $\sum_{n}\lambda_n$ absolutely convergent?

Comment: This seems extremely unlikely to me for the reasons I gave previously (I expect the $\lambda_n$ to grow like $n \log n$; this may possibly even be discernible numerically).

Comment: @Rama1729 Assuming RH  $$\lambda_n=\frac{n\log n}{2}-\frac{\log(2\pi)+1-\gamma}{2}n+n y_n$$ where $(y_n)$ is in $\ell_2$. RH is equivalent to say that $(y_n)$ is in $\ell_2$. This is in my paper Asymptotic of Keiper-Li coefficients, Functiones et approximatio 45 (2011)7--21.